# naming owl ontology in protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege4

I am using Protege 4.2.0.

When I write a new ontology, I can save it to a local file on my machine, e.g., 
GreatNewUpperOntology.owl

If I now want to import that ontology into a new ontology, I can find the file on my hard disk using the Active Ontology tab, Ontology imports panel (lower panel), Direct Imports +, "Import an ontology using a specific file"

The GreatNewUpperOntology imports properly, but shows up with a name like:

untitled-ontology-93 (http://www.semanticweb.org/myname/ontologies/2014/9/untitled-ontology-93)

QUESTION:  Is there a way for me to save my ontology to the semanticweb.org site with the descriptive name I gave the file on my own computer, e.g., "GreatNewUpperOntology"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

A colleague helped me with this one....

> Open the file in Protégé and go to the Active Ontology Tab, if I’m not mistaken you’ll see the “untitled-ontology-93” in the Ontology IRI field. Replace that field with whatever you want the name to be and you should be all set.

That works!